# AIR app: navigateToURL throws a SecurityError #2193

Tags: actionscript-3, security, air, navigatetourl

I'm trying to port an existing web app (ActionScript 3 only project) to AIR, to run as a standalone application. One of its features is opening urls in a browser window. But calling `navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url))` throws this SecurityError:

> SecurityError: Error #2193: Security
>   sandbox violation: navigateToURL:
>   app:/AIRDigE.swf cannot access 
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCPwAr0xnGE.
>     at global/flash.net::navigateToURL()

when run from Flash Builder 4.

Googling doesn't really help me with this specific error number.

[Adobe's reference on Security Sandboxes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html) states that any AIR application running with `Security.sandboxType==Security.APPLICATION` (which my application uses) should be able to connect to any domain, but apparently that doesn't count for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Frank

Comment: What version of the Flex SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Flex SDK 4.1. Could that make a difference?

Comment: I don't think so, I was asking in case you were using a beta or preview version. Honestly I tried this in both flash CS5 and Flash Builder worked just fine. Stumped on this one, unless you've modified your install or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry folks, this morning I found the answer myself: the url that I passed into the URLRequest had a *space* in front of it (it was loaded from an xml feed that is evidently producing faulty urls).

So it seems that a url with an invalid protocol causes that error, and putting a `trim()` around the url fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because of using double backward slashes in the web link like "http:\\www.youtube.com"

Where as I supposed to use "http:**//**www.youtube.com"

Answer (score 0):

try using URLRequest with navigateToURL

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com"));
```

UPDATED:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com"),"blank");
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing. `navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url));`

Comment: can you use "blank" parameter with navigateToURL?

Comment: Actually it is "_blank" not "blank"